# Conflict of merge. But target branch contains this changes

Tags: git

I have two branches: master and develop. There are not any difference in code between this branches.

I mede nev branch new-branch from develop. Changed only one file in new-branch.

I'm going merge new-branch to master but i see conflicts.

In PR i see a lot of changes in new-branch for master. But if i check master it contains this changes. According to PR master don't contains.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"but i see conflicts"_ - then there is a difference.

Comment: When you say "I made new branch from develop", you *might* have used an obsolete local reference if you forgot to fetch beforehand. Might be worth checking, and consider rebasing on (a freshly pulled) develop.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is merely that you don't know what a merge is. When you know what a merge is, you understand how a PR is constructed and what commits and diffs it shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you correctly stated:

> I have two branches: master and develop. There are not any difference in **code** between this branches.

Apparently, there is a significant difference in **commits** on those branches. The question is why? Ideally they would be synced up (so that you don't have the issue you have with your PR).

Here are some possible fixes:

1. If the reason `develop` and `master` have different commits is because you like the commit history of one better, then consider getting rid of the other one. For example, if you like the commit history on `master` but don't like the history on `develop`, then checkout `develop` and reset it (hard) to `master`. Then force push it out and the branches will be identical in both code and commits.
2. If the reason `develop` and `master` have different commits is due to separate merges bringing in the same code, but you wish to keep both histories, then merge `develop` into `master`, and then `master` back into `develop`. Now they will be synced up but the previous histories of both branches is maintained.

After doing either #1 or #2, updating your PR (and possibly also rebasing your branch onto the latest `origin/develop`) should now show just your new changes.

If you wish to not do either #1 or #2, and kick the can down the road for another day, then you'll probably have to do what you've presumably been doing before, which is something similar to either of these options:

- Create a new branch off of `master` and cherry pick your commit(s) onto that branch and PR that into `master`.

or

- Rebase `new-branch` to come off of `master` instead of `develop`. Something like this should do it if you have `new-branch` already checked out: `git rebase --onto origin/master origin/develop`